# Is there any application for mobile by using that I can convert sound from a video to text

Tags: gratis, android, video, google-apps, file-converter

I have one video in English language. Some of words I am not understanding so I though of to convert that video sound to text so that I can read it.

Comment: Welcome aboard :-) Which kind of mobile? Android? iOs? Something lese? Must it be free, so do you have a budget? Do you want an app which will add text subtitles directly into the video, from the soundtrack?

Comment: @Mawg - I have android mobile. I need free application as I am using it for personal things not for business. Subtitle could be ok if it works accurate :). Thank you.

Comment: The state of the art in speech recognition is still not great. If you can't understand what is said, it's likely that software won't either.